# $\vdash\phi \land \diamond\psi \to \diamond(\psi\land\diamond\phi)$ in KB

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs, modal-logic

I've been trying to prove $\vdash\phi \land \diamond\psi \to \diamond(\psi\land\diamond \phi)$ in natural deduction where it's allowed to use $\phi\to \square \diamond \phi$ and/or $\diamond\square\phi\to\phi$ (that is, in $KB)$, but I failed. How can one prove this? I'm not including my work because it consists of dozens of pages and doesn't lead anywhere...

Comment: You've listed the axiom B, but when you say "in natural deduction", I guess you're also including the rules of the modal logic K?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Wikipedia says "K := no conditions", so I'm not sure what rules of K you mean.

Comment: The necessitation rule and the distribution axiom.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, they are included. By "natural deduction" I meant the natural deduction system which includes box-subproofs and diamond-subproofs; and then those axioms can be proven.

Comment: Ok. If you want to ask for a proof in a particular system, it's good practice to include a link to the precise rules of that system. Every logic has a wide variety of proof systems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sketch of the idea, which I'll leave to you to translate into a formal  proof in your system, if you care to.

Let's assume $\phi$ and $\lozenge \psi$. From B and modus ponens, we get $\square\lozenge \phi$, so we get $(\square\lozenge\phi \land \lozenge \psi)$

Now as an instance of the distribution axiom K, we have: $$\square (\lozenge \phi \rightarrow \lnot \psi) \rightarrow (\square \lozenge \phi \rightarrow \square \lnot \psi)$$

The contrapositive of this implication is: $$\lnot (\square\lozenge \phi \rightarrow \square \lnot \psi) \rightarrow \lozenge \lnot (\lozenge \phi \rightarrow \lnot \psi)$$

Turning $\lnot (p\rightarrow q)$ into $p\land \lnot q$ in two places, we get: $$(\square\lozenge \phi \land \lozenge \psi) \rightarrow \lozenge (\psi \land \lozenge \phi)$$

Finally, by modus ponens, we get $$\lozenge (\psi \land \lozenge \phi)$$

Comment: Thanks! It seems I'd have never come up with the idea of considering $\square (\lozenge \phi \rightarrow \lnot \psi) \rightarrow (\square \lozenge \phi \rightarrow \square \lnot \psi)$.